# LVM Extend... not sure the filesystem

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, lvm, fdisk

I would like to extend my LVM partition.  First I did

```
lvextend -L +100G /dev/server/home
```

Now I still have to extend the filesystem.  The tutorials tell me to use `resize2fs`, but that only works for ext2 and ext3.  I'm not even sure what filesystem I have...

```
fdisk /dev/server/home/
```

doesn't work... how do I know what kind of filesystem I have on my lvm partition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's a mounted filesystem, you can use `df -hT`:

```
$ df -hT
Filesystem    Type    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1     ext4    5.5G  3.0G  2.3G  58% /
none      devtmpfs    229M  252K  229M   1% /dev
none         tmpfs    233M     0  233M   0% /dev/shm
none         tmpfs    233M  100K  233M   1% /var/run
none         tmpfs    233M     0  233M   0% /var/lock
none         tmpfs    233M     0  233M   0% /lib/init/rw
```

The "type" column indicates the filesystem in use; the "filesystem" column is the partition/device where it's located.  (This example is from an Ubuntu Lucid system; my Debian system displays the root partition filetype as *rootfs* instead of the correct *ext3*.)

If the filesystem is not mounted, or *df* displays it as type *rootfs*, you can use a tool such as *blkid*, which checks the device more directly:

```
$ sudo blkid /path/to/filesystem/device
/dev/sda1: UUID="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" TYPE="ext4"
```

Comment: Thanks!  Turned out the answer was "xfs" so I had to use the "xfs_growfs" command

Answer (score 0):

A recent version of GNU file will also tell you (so long as provide the flags for it to follow symlinks and look 'in' device special files):

> [dan@khorium ~]$ **sudo file -Ls /dev/vgcore/home**
>   /dev/vgcore/home: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data (needs journal recovery) (extents) (large files) (huge files)